# Unity UI doesn't show in the hierarchy

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, hierarchy

I'm working on Unity and I realize that when I want to create a **UI/Text**, the **UI** doesn't show up in **Create** when I right click in the hierarchy. However, if I go on another computer in my class, it works just fine but it isn't mine so I need to stay on that computer with a UI who disappeared completely from the hierarchy.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Can you do a print screen and show us?

Comment: Which version of Unity do you use ? Maybe, you can create your object from the "GameObject > UI" menu at the top of the Editor ? [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mafGI.png)

Comment: @Hellium I use the 5.5.0f3 version.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Here's a link: http://chib-forty.deviantart.com/art/Screenshot-3-665201247?ga_submit_new=10%3A1487816201

Comment: @ScottChamberlain The problem however isn't on the computer at my house. It's when I have my classes. You see, when I do the right click, the UI section isn't there.

Comment: Get the picture from the computer in the class. Also, ask the teacher for help asking why you don't have that menu item, that is what the teacher is for, asking questions.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I showed to him and even himself didn't know how it was possible. I will try to reinstall Unity on this computer

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what is happening?

Comment: But UI shows on your picture. Between Audio and Particle System.

Comment: @Everts That's because I was on my computer at home. It works just fine.

Comment: @Everts However, when I'm in my class, it doesn't show